# SQL Equivalent to LAG() to create a computed table

Tags: sql, azure, powerapps

I'm fairly new to SQL and I'm trying to create a computed column in a table that calculates the DateDiff on a column between the current row and the previous row.

Now all is fine and dandy doing a query with Select to display this value:

```
SELECT *, 

Case When INCM<> lag(INCM) over(ORDER BY INCM ASC, Submit_Date ASC) Then 0 else DateDiff(mi,Submit_Date, lag(Submit_Date) over (ORDER BY INCM ASC, Submit_Date ASC)) End As Diff
  FROM [OP].[Ticket_Work_Info]
```

But as I recently found out, when adding a computed column with this logic to the existing table I get an error saying Windowed Functions can only be used with Select or Order By.

I've been searching everywhere for an equivalent to LAG to use to create a computed column on a table.

In the meantime I ended up creating a view with this piece of code, but that's not really what I want to do going forward.

Can someone give me a hand?

Regards,

Comment: You can only do this using a user-defined function. A better alternative is to use a view.

Comment: In a computed column there are no other rows to consider so allowing windowing, aggregate or analytical functions doesn't make sense. `LAG()` over which result set?

Comment: Understood, I'll just carry on with the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some reasoning on *why* computed columns can only refer to values in the current row (and deterministic functions and constants).  Consider a definition such as:

```
create t (
    t_id int,
    a varchar(255),
    x int,
    prev_x as (lag(x) over (order by t_id)
);
```

And some sample data:

```
id      y      x
 1      z      6
 2      abc    28
 3      z      496
```

This looks fine.  But, consider this query:

```
select t.*
from t
where a <> 'abc';
```

Should the value of `x_prev` for the third row be 28 or 6?

I guess no one wanted to make a decision on this.  Instead, the idea is that a *row* is well-defined, so the filtering conditions do not affect the values within a row.

Comment: Thanks I'll just go with a View